# ReferenceError: navigator is not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have this server code setup to fetch audio and images files.
Earlier it was working fine but now I am getting this error

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => { ^ ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

I am unable to debug this error and don't know the reason also since before it was working and i haven't changed anything since in code.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

// Allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors());
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
  // Collection for recorded data.
  let data = [];

  // Recorder instance using the stream.
  // Also set the stream as the src for the audio element.
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  audio.srcObject = stream;

  recorder.addEventListener('start', e => {
    // Empty the collection when starting recording.
    data.length = 0;
  });

  recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
    // Push recorded data to collection.
    data.push(event.data);
  });

  // Create a Blob when recording has stopped.
  recorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
    const blob = new Blob(data, {
      'type': 'audio/mp3'
    });
    sendAudioFile(blob);
  });

  // Start the recording.
  recorder.start();
});
const sendAudioFile = file => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('audio-file', file);
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/audioUpload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
};
// Serve static files from the 'public' folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Serve a list of image file names
app.get('/images', (req, res) => {
  // Read the contents of the 'images' folder
  const imageDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images');
  fs.readdir(imageDir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error reading images folder');
      return;
    }
    // Return a list of image file names
    res.json(files);
  });
});
app.get('/audio', (req, res) => {
  // Read the contents of the 'images' folder
  const imageDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'audio');
  fs.readdir(imageDir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Error reading images folder');
      return;
    }
    // Return a list of image file names
    res.json(files);
  });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I did some search and found that navigator is deprecated , is that the reason I am getting this error ?

Comment: The navigator API isn't available in Node.js. Only on the browser.